# Is there any way to add dynamic validation on client side?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, validation

I'm developing an ASP.NET MVC with C# and .NET Framework 4.7.

I have this on a View:
[image]

The value on the right will have a maximum length depending on what we have selected on the select on its left.

This is the view code:

```
for (int vDataIndex = 0; vDataIndex < Model.VariableDataList[levelIndex].VariableDataForLevel.Count; vDataIndex++)
{
    <tr>
        <td>
            <div class="group">
                @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.VariableDataList[levelIndex].VariableDataForLevel[vDataIndex].ProductionOrderId)
                @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.VariableDataList[levelIndex].VariableDataForLevel[vDataIndex].AggregationLevelConfigurationId)
                @Html.DropDownListFor(
                    m => m.VariableDataList[levelIndex].VariableDataForLevel[vDataIndex].VariableDataId,
                    new SelectList(Model.variableDataItems, "Id", "Name",
                    Model.VariableDataList[levelIndex].VariableDataForLevel[vDataIndex].VariableDataId))
            </div>
        </td>
        <td>
            <div class="group">
                @Html.TextBoxFor(
                    m => m.VariableDataList[levelIndex].VariableDataForLevel[vDataIndex].Value)
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.VariableDataList[levelIndex].VariableDataForLevel[vDataIndex].Value)
            </div>
        </td>
    </tr>
}
```

And the model classes:

```
public class VariableDataGrouped
{
    public string LevelName { get; set; }
    public List<Models.VariableData> VariableDataForLevel { get; set; }
}

public class CreateVariableDataViewModel
{
    public readonly List<GenericIdNameType> variableDataItems;

    [ ... ]

    public List<VariableDataGrouped> VariableDataList { get; set; }

    public CreateVariableDataViewModel()
    {
        variableDataItems = new List<GenericIdNameType>();

        foreach (VariableDataKey key in VariableDataKey.GetAllVariableData())
        {
            GenericIdNameType gType = new GenericIdNameType()
            {
                Id = key.Id,
                Name = key.Description
            };

            variableDataItems.Add(gType);
        }
    }
}
public class Models.VariableData
{
    [ ... ]

    [Required(ErrorMessageResourceType = typeof(Resources.Resources),
          ErrorMessageResourceName = "VariableDataValueRequired")]
    [StringLength(50, ErrorMessageResourceType = typeof(Resources.Resources),
                  ErrorMessageResourceName = "VariableDataValueLong")]
    public string Value { get; set; }
}
```

Maybe I can store also the length in `CreateVariableDataViewModel.variableDataItems` and create a dynamic validation using it depending on the `Id` selected on the select.

Do you know how can I create a dynamic validation depending on the `Id` selected?

Comment: You need to create an attribute that derives from `ValidationAttribute` and implements `IClientValidatable`. Refer [The Complete Guide To Validation In ASP.NET MVC 3 - Part 2](https://www.devtrends.co.uk/blog/the-complete-guide-to-validation-in-asp.net-mvc-3-part-2)

Comment: Fluent validation may be the solution.

Comment: You can do the validation on the client side using javascript/jquery.